# Flutterwave Android payment integration - cannot process payment - error unable to retrieve transaction fee

Tags: android, payment, flutterwave

I'm using Rave for the first time, it looked so flexible and easier to integrate, but along the line. I got stuck with testing, I'm using only card and bank payments methods.

1. when I choose the card to and enter some test cards from the test card link https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#test-cards-1
   I get 2 errors, => "unable to retrieve transaction fees" but in my `logcat` I see => " only test cards `ree` allowed," of which were using the test cards. And am also on staging mode which I assume is correct while testing with test keys.
2. When I use the bank tab I get some error in `JSON` toasted, but display later => "parents_limit not defined". Not just that I give this errors, I still found transactions of the bank payment types recorded on my dashboard. This confuses me more since I didn't get the payment success message so I can verify and give value to the customer.

I have integrated everything as per guideline in Rave docs, which calls my make payment. from https://github.com/Flutterwave/rave-android

variable for implementation

```
 //online payment
    String[] fullname;
    String email = "";
    String fName = "";
    String lName = "";
    String narration = "Payment for Riidit App activation";
    String txRef;
    String country = "NG";
    String currency = "NGN";
    private String mUsername, userID, mEmail;
```

the payment method

```
private void makePayment(int amount) {
        txRef = email + " " + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        try {
            fullname = mUsername.split(" ");
            fName = fullname[0];
            lName = fullname[1];

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
        Create instance of RavePayManager
         */
        new RavePayManager(this).setAmount(amount)
                .setCountry(country)
                .setCurrency(currency)
                .setEmail(email)
                .setfName(fName)
                .setlName(lName)
                .setNarration(narration)
                .setPublicKey(RiiditUtilTool.getPublicKey())
                .setEncryptionKey(RiiditUtilTool.getEncryptionKey())
                .setTxRef(txRef)
                .acceptAccountPayments(true)
                .acceptCardPayments(true)
                .acceptMpesaPayments(false)
                .acceptGHMobileMoneyPayments(false)
                .onStagingEnv(false)
                .allowSaveCardFeature(true)
                .withTheme(R.style.DefaultTheme)
                .initialize();
    }
```

//called from below

```
 private void payOnline() 
{
    makePayment(amount);
}


public void onActivateOnlineClick(View v) {
        payOnline();
    }
```

// expecting result of payment here either fail or success

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RaveConstants.RAVE_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
            String message = data.getStringExtra("response");
            if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // get a PIN and SERIAL no when payment succeeds
                getGetPinAndSerialForPaidUser();

            } else if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_CANCELLED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Payment CANCELLED " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want when this event is triggered, it will make the payment to using the value set in the amount and return status in the `onActivityResult` above where I can check and give value to the user

Comment: Join the [Flutterwave Developer Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/flutterwavedevelopers/shared_invite/enQtMjU2MjkyNDM5MTcxLWFlOWNlYmE5MTIxNjAwYzc5MDVjZjNhYTJjNTA0ZTQyNDJlMDhhZjJkN2QwZGJmNWMyODhlYjMwNGUyZDQxNTE). You'll get a quick response on there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are using the api keys which are for testing and if you are on staging mode(testing) then set this to true .**onStagingEnv(true)** and test after that.